# not getting all tasks from task scheduler

Tags: powershell

we monitor tasks from multiple servers, the following script collect the repetition of each task. this helps automation when rolling out scripts in PROD env.

```
$ScheduledTasks = get-scheduledtask 
Write-Host "Task;Repetition"
$data = foreach ($item in $ScheduledTasks) {
    [string]$Name       = ($item.TaskName)
    [string]$Repetition = ($item.Triggers.Repetition | select -ExpandProperty interval)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Name'       = $Name
    'Repetition' = $Repetition
}}
$data | foreach-object  {write-output "$($_.Name); $($_.Repetition)"}
```

somehow this does not collect all tasks, but only the ones from the se two subfolders. can you help understanding why it is not collecting from *Task Scheduler Library*?

[image: ..]

Comment: Try running as Administrator

Comment: I agree with @Theo , under a standard users context you will only see tasks that can be executed by that user or a group that the user belongs to. Anything that is ran outside of this `system` etc will not be visible without full administrative access.